# Extracting polygon features touched by a line feature

Tags: qgis, clip, intersect, ppygis

I have polygon features (like streets or fields) and a line feature over them. I want to have all the polygon features touched by the line in a separate layer. If I run clip or intersect it only outputs a line (as expected). But is there any way to actually do this automatically in QGIS?

I have all my layers and data saved in a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Try a select by location or by expression then export selected feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use extract by location from `Processing Toolbox > Vector Selection > Extract by location`. In the `Extract features from` field, select your polygon layer from the dropdown menu. and in `By comparing features from` field, select your line layer. Choose one or more `geometric predicate` and then `Run`. This should give you a new layer with extracted features from the polygon layer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option is [Extract by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisextractbyexpression):

> creates a new vector layer that only contains matching features from
> an input layer. The criteria for adding features to the resulting
> layer is based on a QGIS expression

I want to extract from nature (polygon layer) which intersects railroad (line layer):

`overlay_intersects(layer:='railroad')`

[image]